# Import a file from a subdirectory?

Tags: python, python-import

I have a file called `tester.py`, located on `/project`.

`/project` has a subdirectory called `lib`, with a file called `BoxTime.py`:

```
/project/tester.py
/project/lib/BoxTime.py
```

I want to import `BoxTime` from `tester`. I have tried this:

```
import lib.BoxTime
```

Which resulted:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "./tester.py", line 3, in <module>
    import lib.BoxTime
ImportError: No module named lib.BoxTime
```

Any ideas how to import `BoxTime` from the subdirectory?

**EDIT**

The `__init__.py` was the problem, but don't forget to refer to `BoxTime` as `lib.BoxTime`, or use:

```
import lib.BoxTime as BT
...
BT.bt_function()
```

Comment: Seems he is importing `lib/BoxTime` _to_ `tester`.

Comment: Python 3.3+ has Implicit Namespace Packages that allow it to create a packages without an `__init__.py` file. Check [Is `__init__.py` not required for packages in Python 3.3+](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37139786/is-init-py-not-required-for-packages-in-python-3-3).

Answer (score 697, accepted):

Take a look at the **[Packages documentation (Section 6.4)](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/modules.html#packages)**.

In short, you need to put a blank file named

```
__init__.py
```

in the `lib` directory.

Comment: Why does it feel *hacky*? It's the way python marks safe/available import directories.

Comment: Not only it marks safe/available import directories, but also provides a way to run some initialization code when importing a directory name.

Comment: Yes this is hacky and even dirty, and in my opinion the language shouldn't impose its way of loading files across the filesystem. In PHP we solved the problem by letting the userland code register multiple autoloading functions that are called when a namespace/class is missing. Then the community has produced the PSR-4 standard and Composer implements it, and nowadays nobody has to worry about that. And no stupid hardcoded `__init__` files (but if you want it, just register an autoloading hook ! This is the difference between _hacky_ and _hackable_).

Comment: @YaShChaudhary It didn't work for me until I changed the reference to library: foldername.modulename

Comment: @mimic Your foldername.modulename worked for me doing an explict dynamic load with importlib.import_module.

Comment: The necessary `__init__.py` file was at least not comfortable, may it be hacky or not. And this point got resolved in Python 3.3: A package can be made up without the file.

Comment: See also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37139786/is-init-py-not-required-for-packages-in-python-3-3

Comment: Related, but not OP's wish, is to install the lib into the local pip: `cd your-git-work-tree && pip install -e .` Then you can simply use the library via the pip system.

Answer (score 224):

- Create a subdirectory named `lib`.
- Create an empty file named `lib\__init__.py`.
- In `lib\BoxTime.py`, write a function `foo()` like this:

  ```
  def foo():
      print "foo!"
  ```
- In your client code in the directory above `lib`, write:

  ```
  from lib import BoxTime
  BoxTime.foo()
  ```
- Run your client code. You will get:

  ```
  foo!
  ```

---

Much later -- in linux, it would look like this:

```
% cd ~/tmp
% mkdir lib
% touch lib/__init__.py
% cat > lib/BoxTime.py << EOF
heredoc> def foo():
heredoc>     print "foo!"
heredoc> EOF
% tree lib
lib
├── BoxTime.py
└── __init__.py

0 directories, 2 files
% python 
Python 2.7.6 (default, Mar 22 2014, 22:59:56) 
[GCC 4.8.2] on linux2
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> from lib import BoxTime
>>> BoxTime.foo()
foo!
```

Comment: Could you provide a link to the Python documentation where this is explained? Thanks!

Comment: Let's make that link clickable: https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/modules.html#packages

Comment: Nice walkthrough for implementing a package `lib`

Comment: please note: subdirs shall not contain dashes or dots, but underscores are valid. for me that seems like the same restrictions as for other symbol names, but i have not yet digged it down to documentation level.

Comment: underscores => python3 (too late for editing the comment)

Comment: @AlexanderStohr You are talking about rules for importing? Not something specific to an error I made in my code sample, right?

Comment: @hughdbrown - i was talking about what will work and even more on what might not work with the argument of "from".

Comment: what if i want to select what sub folder to load the module from via a cli argument? `from <arg> import module` doesn't work

Comment: Leading zeroes are invalid. For eg, filenames like "000abc.py" don't work

Comment: Take care to name your file also BoxTime.py - not boxtime.py etc. if you import with "from lib import BoxTime" - even as my classname was BoxTime it failed when not naming the file accordingly.

Answer (score 106):

You can try inserting it in `sys.path`:

```
sys.path.insert(0, './lib')
import BoxTime
```

Comment: This is great if you for some reason can't or won't create the __init__.py file.

Comment: It works if you run python from the "project" directory. The "." is interpreted relative to your current working directory, not relative to the directory where the file you're executing lives. Say you `cd /data`, `python ../project/tester.py`. Then it won't work.

Comment: This worked for me. I prefer this over an *init*.py file, it makes for cleaner import statements.

Comment: This works MUCH better and is the "correct" solution.  __init__.py messes up packages like boto that have their own child folders with modules.

Comment: @jpihl You have to create (at least) a empy file named ***__init__.py*** to allow python import modules from that folder. I've tried that solution and works perfectly (v2.7.6).

Comment: This solution works when you are not running an app in the parent folder of the modules you are trying to import and when you don't have the `__init__.py` in the module folders.

Comment: @minsk You didn't, by any chance, happen to change the path AFTER attempting the import, instead of before? (I did at first, simply from old habit of beginning with imports.)

Comment: A hint if you please, when in troubles with relative path as mentioned by @morningstar run it like:  sys.path.append(sys.path[0] + '/lib')

Comment: I wish I could give 1000 points for this answer. this answer helped to import a big detectron module. in the project If I havent added sys.path.insert(0, './detectron2') I must have added detectron2 in each file's import line in whole project

Answer (score 54):

I am writing this down because everyone seems to suggest that you have to create a `lib` directory.

You don't need to name your sub-directory `lib`. You can name it `anything` provided you put an `__init__.py` into it.

You can do that by entering the following command in a linux shell:

```
$ touch anything/__init__.py
```

So now you have this structure:

```
$ ls anything/
__init__.py
mylib.py

$ ls
main.py
```

Then you can import `mylib` into `main.py` like this:

```
from anything import mylib 

mylib.myfun()
```

You can also import functions and classes like this:

```
from anything.mylib import MyClass
from anything.mylib import myfun

instance = MyClass()
result = myfun()
```

Any variable function or class you place inside `__init__.py` can also be accessed:

```
import anything

print(anything.myvar)
```

Or like this:

```
from anything import myvar

print(myvar)
```

Comment: My folder structure is  `utils\__init__.py` and `utils\myfile.py`. (Utils contain both files) This is how I am trying to import `from utils.myfile import myMethod`. But I get `ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'utils'`. What could be wrong?            **P.S:**  I am using `Django` and trying to import in `views.py` which is at the same level as `utils` folder

Comment: It is possible to use absolute paths when importing modules and run your program with `PYTHONPATH=. python path/to/program.py`

Comment: clearest answer! thanks

Answer (score 30):

Try `import .lib.BoxTime`. For more information read about relative import in [PEP 328](http://dinsdale.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0328/#guido-s-decision).

Comment: I don't think I've ever seen that syntax used before. Is there strong reason (not) to use this method?

Comment: Why wasn't this the answer. Sure, if you want to do the whole packages thing, you should do that. But that's not what the original question was.

Comment: This gives me: ValueError: Attempted relative import in non-package

Comment: This only works if the file you're importing from is itself part of a package. If not, you'll receive the error that @Alex pointed out.

Comment: (Tried in Python 3) This results in `SyntaxError: invalid syntax`. PyLance tells me `Relative imports cannot be used with "import .a" form; use "from . import a" instead`. In this case this would be `from .lib import BoxTime`

Answer (score 20):

Does your lib directory contain a `__init__.py` file?

Python uses `__init__.py` to determine if a directory is a module.

Answer (score 20):

**Full example included**

This basically covers all cases (make sure you have `__init__.py` in relative/path/to/your/lib/folder):

```
import sys, os
sys.path.append(os.path.dirname(os.path.realpath(__file__)) + "/relative/path/to/your/lib/folder")
import someFileNameWhichIsInTheFolder
...
somefile.foo()
```

**Example:**

You have in your project folder:

```
/root/myproject/app.py
```

You have in another project folder:

```
/root/anotherproject/utils.py
/root/anotherproject/__init__.py
```

You want to use `/root/anotherproject/utils.py` and call foo function which is in it.

So you write in app.py:

```
import sys, os
sys.path.append(os.path.dirname(os.path.realpath(__file__)) + "/../anotherproject")
import utils

utils.foo()
```

Comment: if you're using `os.path` you probably want to use `os.path.join((os.path.dirname(os.path.realpath(__file__)),'..','anotherproject')` instead of hardcoding the '/' in your path concatenation.

Comment: Why can't you just do `"../anotherproject"` without the `os.path.dirname()`?

Comment: @MosheRabaev - It is good practice to use os.path functions. In case of wrting "../anotherproject" and moving the code to Windows OS, the code will break!
os.path utils knows how to return correct path considering the OS the code running on. for more info https://docs.python.org/2/library/os.path.html

Comment: @MosheRabaev and if you use ".." without the `dirname(realpath(__file__))`, then it will compute the path relative to your current working directory when you run the script, not relative to where the script lives.

Answer (score 8):

Create an empty file  `__init__.py` in subdirectory /lib.
And add at the begin of main code

```
from __future__ import absolute_import
```

then

```
import lib.BoxTime as BT
...
BT.bt_function()
```

or better

```
from lib.BoxTime import bt_function
...
bt_function()
```

Comment: This is the only right fix that worked for me in Pycharm, thanks

Answer (score 6):

Just an addition to these answers.

If you want to import **all** files from **all subdirectories**, you can add this to the root of your file.

```py
import sys, os
sys.path.extend([f'./{name}' for name in os.listdir(".") if os.path.isdir(name)])
```

And then you can simply import files from the subdirectories just as if these files are inside the current directory.

### Working example

If I have the following directory with subdirectories in my project...

```sh
.
├── a.py
├── b.py
├── c.py
├── subdirectory_a
│   ├── d.py
│   └── e.py
├── subdirectory_b
│   └── f.py
├── subdirectory_c
│   └── g.py
└── subdirectory_d
    └── h.py
```

I can put the following code inside my `a.py` file

```py
import sys, os
sys.path.extend([f'./{name}' for name in os.listdir(".") if os.path.isdir(name)])

# And then you can import files just as if these files are inside the current directory

import b
import c
import d
import e
import f
import g
import h
```

In other words, this code will abstract from which directory the file is coming from.

Comment: Hey! I modified your one liner to `sys.path.extend([f'{item[0]}' for item in os.walk(".") if os.path.isdir(item[0])])` and now it scrapes recursively from the project's directory. Thank you for your answer! Super useful.

Comment: @Shrout1 , Good job!

Answer (score 2):

For this folder hierarchy diagram example:

```
/project/tester.py    
/project/lib/BoxTime.py
```

1- Create a blank py file `__init__.py` inside **lib** folder

2- In the caller py file tester.py add theses code lines

```
import os, sys
sys.path.insert(0,'lib')# insert the folder lib in system path
from BoxTime import Function_name # from the py file import the needed function
```

Easy explanation can be found in [here](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/python-import-module-from-different-directory/).

Notice: This is refered to as creating/importing modules in/from different folder.

Personel experience: I tried to create module from jupyter notebook, it did not not work (maybe I done it improperly using .ipynb), I needed to do it manually outside the juypyter notebook, or using other IDE (e.g. pycharm).

Comment: sys.path.insert was key for me.  Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

create_card.py

```
 init():
   print('Hello world!')
```

app.py

```
import create_card

create_card.init()
```

if you want to import only required functions

```
from create_card import init
```

If you have nested directories (Ex: modules/aadhaar/create-card.py)

`import modules.aadhaar.create_card as create_card` or `from modules.aadhaar.create_card import init`

Answer (score -1):

`/project/tester.py`

`/project/lib/BoxTime.py`

create blank file `__init__.py` down the line till you reach the file

`/project/lib/somefolder/BoxTime.py`

`#lib` -- needs has two items one `__init__.py` and a directory named somefolder
`#somefolder` has two items `boxtime.py` and `__init__.py`

Answer (score -3):

try this:

`from lib import BoxTime`

Comment: without any explanation this isn't very useful.