# How do I import variable packages in Python like using variable variables ($$) in PHP?

Tags: python, variables, variable-variables

I want to import some package depending on which value the user chooses.

The default is `file1.py`:

```py
from files import file1
```

If user chooses `file2`, it should be :

```py
from files import file2
```

In PHP, I can do this using [variable variables](http://php.net/manual/en/language.variables.variable.php):

```php
$file_name = 'file1';
include($$file_name);
```

```php
$file_name = 'file2';
include($$file_name);
```

How can I do this in Python?

Comment: Don't do this! Use input is not usually trustworthy and blinding evaluating code based on it it a bad idea.

Comment: thanks, i am using default set to import now.

Answer (score 81, accepted):

Python doesn't have a feature that's directly equivalent to PHP's "variable variables". To get a "variable variable"'s value (or the value of any other expression) you can use the `eval` function.

```
foo = "Hello World"
print eval("foo")
```

However, this can't be used in an `import` statement.

It is possible to use the [`__import__`](http://docs.python.org/library/functions.html#__import__) function to import using a variable.

```
package = "os"
name = "path"

imported = getattr(__import__(package, fromlist=[name]), name)
```

is equivalent to

```
from os import path as imported
```

Answer (score 46):

Old thread, but I needed the answer, so someone else still might...

There's a cleaner way to do this in Python 2.7+:

```
import importlib


my_module = importlib.import_module("package.path.%s" % module_name)
```

Comment: Tip: you'll need a `package.path.__init__.py` for [import to work](http://stackoverflow.com/a/1260813/673991) at all.

Answer (score 39):

As [Fredrik Lundh states:](https://web.archive.org/web/20200917011425/http://effbot.org/zone/import-confusion.htm)

> Anyway, here’s how these statements and functions work:
>
> `import X` imports the module X, and creates a reference to that module
> in the current namespace. Or in other words, after you’ve run this
> statement, you can use `X.name` to refer to things defined in module X.
>
> `from X import *` imports the module X, and creates references in the
> current namespace to all public objects defined by that module (that
> is, everything that doesn’t have a name starting with “_”). Or in
> other words, after you’ve run this statement, you can simply use a
> plain name to refer to things defined in module X. But X itself is not
> defined, so `X.name` doesn’t work. And if name was already defined, it
> is replaced by the new version. And if name in X is changed to point
> to some other object, your module won’t notice.
>
> `from X import a, b, c` imports the module X, and creates references in
> the current namespace to the given objects. Or in other words, you can
> now use `a` and `b` and `c` in your program.
>
> **Finally, `X = __import__(‘X’)` works like `import X`, with the difference
> that you 1) pass the module name as a string, and 2) explicitly assign
> it to a variable in your current namespace.**

And by the way that's the last one method that you're intrested in.

Simply write (for example):

```
var = "datetime"
module = __import__(var)
```

Answer (score 6):

Basing myself on `mattjbray`'s answer:

```
from importlib import import_module

# lookup in a set is in constant time
safe_names = {"file1.py", "file2.py", "file3.py", ...}

user_input = ...

if user_input in safe_names:
    file = import_module(user_input)
else:
    print("Nope, not doing this.")
```

Saves a few lines of code, and allows you to set `safe_names` programmatically, or load multiple modules and assign them to a dict, for example.

Answer (score 5):

It's probably a very bad idea to let the user choose what to import.  Packages can execute code on import, so you're effectively allowing a user to arbitrarily execute code on your system! Much safer to do something like

```
if user_input == 'file1.py':
  from files import file1 as file
elif user_input == 'file2.py':
  from files import file2 as file
else:
  file = None
  print "Sorry, you can't import that file"
```