# How can I import a python file through a command prompt?

Tags: python, python-2.7, import, command

I am working on project euler and wanted to time all of my code. What I have is directory of files in the form 'problemxxx.py' where xxx is the problem number. Each of these files has a `main()` function that returns the answer. So I have created a file called run.py, located in the same directory as the problem files. I am able to get the name of the file through command prompt. But when I try to import the problem file, I continue to get `ImportError: No module named problem`. Below is the code for run.py so far, along with the command prompt used.

```
# run.py
import sys
problem = sys.argv[1]
import problem         # I have also tired 'from problem import main' w/ same result

# will add timeit functions later, but trying to get this to run first
problem.main()
```

The command prompts that I have tried are the following: (both of which give the ImportError stated above)

```
python run.py problem001
python run.py problem001.py
```

How can I import the function `main()` from the file problem001.py? Does importing not work with the file name stored as a variable? Is there a better solution than trying to get the file name through command prompt? Let me know if I need to add more information, and thank you for any help!

Comment: See this answer:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6677424/how-do-i-import-variable-packages-in-python-like-using-variable-variables-i

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this by using the [`__import__()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#__import__) function.

```
# run.py
import sys
problem = __import__(sys.argv[1], fromlist=["main"])         # I have also tired 'from problem import main' w/ same result
problem.main()
```

Then if you have `problem001.py` like this:

```
def main():
    print "In sub_main"
```

Calling `python run.py problem001` prints:

```
In sub_main
```

A cleaner way to do this (instead of the `__import__` way) is to use the [`importlib`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/importlib.html#importlib.import_module) module. Your `run.py` needs to changes:

```
import importlib
problem = importlib.import_module(sys.argv[1])
```

Alternatives are mentioned in this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/301134/dynamic-module-import-in-python).

Comment: Thanks for providing multiple options, I like the clean way with use of importlib. Would that be the recommended way since it has been mentioned that __import__ is not recommended?

Comment: Yes, importlib is a better option.

Answer (score 1):

For sure! You can use __ *import_* built-in function like `__import__(problem)`. However this is not recommended to use, because it is not nice in terms of coding-style. I think if you are using this for testing purposes then you should use unittest module, either way try to avoid these constructions.

Regards

Answer (score -1):

You can use exec() trick:

```py
    import sys
    problem = sys.argv[1] 
    exec('import %s' % problem)
    exec('%s.main()' % problem)
```