# How to import *variables* from a dynamically chosen module?

Tags: python, dynamic, import, module

This is essentially a re-ask of [my first question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63627303/how-to-import-variables-from-dynamically-chosen-file-in-python), which was closed without being answered properly. I'll try to be more verbose here and detail why [the suggested duplicate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6677424/how-do-i-import-variable-packages-in-python-like-using-variable-variables-i) fails to solve my issue.

The project I'm working on is being run in two distinct environments. To cope, we have two nearly identical files, say, here_file.py and there_file.py, that define the various hostnames, URLs, file paths, etc. that are unique to the environments. An environment variable controls the choice of file to import. That is, our imports include a section like:

```py
if os.getenv('location') == 'here':
    from here_file import A, very, long, list, of, variables
if os.getenv('location') == 'there':
    from there_file import A, very, long, list, of, variables
```

The suggested duplicate shows how to use `importlib.import_module()` to import different files depending on some condition. I had hoped a solution to this problem would look something like:

```py
from importlib import import_module
var_file = import_module(f"{os.getenv('location')}_file")
from var_file import A, very, long, list, of, variables
```

Unfortunately, I was already able to get that far in my own testing. Here is a minimal example:

```py
# here_file.py
variable = "I'm here."
```

```py
# there_file.py
variable = "You're there."
```

```py
# Option 1) This works, and is our current solution
import os

if os.getenv('location') == 'here':
    from here_file import variable
if os.getenv('location') == 'there':
    from there_file import variable

if __name__ == "__main__":
    print("variable =", variable)
```

```py
# Option 2) This works, but it isn't the answer I'm looking for
import os
from importlib import import_module

location = os.getenv('location')
location_module = import_module(f'{location}_file')

if __name__ == "__main__":
    print("variable =", location_module.variable)
```

Here is what I would like to work, but fails:

```py
# Option 3) This fails
import os
from importlib import import_module

location = os.getenv('location')
location_module = import_module(f'{location}_file')
from location_module import variable

if __name__ == "__main__":
    print("variable =", variable)
```

fails with

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "import_fail.py", line 6, in <module>
    from location_module import variable
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'location_module'
```

I think, perhaps, I should be using a loader or `getattr()` ... or something. The one-liner `from import_module(f'{location}_file') import variable` hits a syntax error (though it'd be slick if it worked).

It may be that Option 3, importing variables from a dynamically specified module (which is how I phrased the question!), is impossible, in which case Option 2 will do.

---

Comment: You should edit the original question and ask for it to be reopened, rather than posting a new question.

Comment: Why do you want to use `from location_module import variable` instead of `variable = location_module.variable`, which is the obvious thing to do based on option #2.

Comment: @Barmar, sorry about the etiquette misstep. But in my defense, the blue box at the top said: "Your post has been associated with a similar question. If this question doesn’t resolve your question, ask a new one." where "ask a new one" is a link to posing a new question. I've deleted the old one now, if that helps.