# trouble with supervisor starting gunicorn

Tags: python, django, virtualenv, gunicorn, supervisord

I am new to django and getting familiar with it.

I am using supervisor and gunicorn. I am following this book "practical django projects". Everything django, supervisor etc are running in virtualenv.

I am trying to create a standalone app of django. I created a folder named blog and placed it under home directory. And then I added the path to PYTHONPATH. I can clearly see the python path added successfully from ipython. But then when I add this blog to installed apps settings of my django project, supervisor started giving trouble.

I have seen the log files and it `No module named blog`

My supervisor conf file is this

```
[program:gunicorn]
command = ./manage.py run_gunicorn -w 4 -k gevent
directory = /home/krishna/workspace/django/learn/
user = krishna
autostart = true
autorestart = true
stdout_logfile = /var/log/supervisor/gunicorn.log
stderr_logfile = /var/log/supervisor/gunicorn_err.log
```

But what frustrates me more is that When I use the command which is exactly in supervisor conf file in the terminal, gunicorn starts peacefully.

Additional info:

output of sys.path

```
/home/krishna/.virtualenvs/py1/bin
/home/krishna/workspace/django/apps
/home/krishna/workspace/django
/home/krishna/workspace
/home/krishna/workspace/django/learn
/home/krishna/.virtualenvs/py1/lib/python2.7
/home/krishna/.virtualenvs/py1/lib/python2.7/plat-x86_64-linux-gnu
/home/krishna/.virtualenvs/py1/lib/python2.7/lib-tk
/home/krishna/.virtualenvs/py1/lib/python2.7/lib-old
/home/krishna/.virtualenvs/py1/lib/python2.7/lib-dynload
/usr/lib/python2.7
/usr/lib/python2.7/plat-x86_64-linux-gnu
/usr/lib/python2.7/lib-tk
/home/krishna/.virtualenvs/py1/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages
/home/krishna/.virtualenvs/py1/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/IPython/extensions
```

My blog folder is in `/home/krishna/workspace/django/apps`

Edit: I am including the file structure of my blog folder

```
drwxr-xr-x 2 krishna krishna  4096 Feb 22 01:12 .
drwxr-xr-x 3 krishna krishna  4096 Feb 22 00:17 ..
-rw-r--r-- 1 krishna krishna     0 Feb 22 00:18 admin.py
-rw-r--r-- 1 krishna krishna   136 Feb 22 01:09 admin.pyc
-rw-r--r-- 1 krishna krishna 12288 Feb 22 00:27 .admin.py.swp
-rw-r--r-- 1 krishna krishna     0 Feb 22 00:17 __init__.py
-rw-r--r-- 1 krishna krishna   139 Feb 22 00:33 __init__.pyc
-rw-r--r-- 1 krishna krishna   222 Feb 22 00:23 models.py
-rw-r--r-- 1 krishna krishna   743 Feb 22 00:33 models.pyc
-rw-r--r-- 1 krishna krishna     0 Feb 22 00:18 views.py
```

Comment: Is there anything in gunicorn.log or gunicorn_err.log?

Comment: As I have already mentioned the error log says module blog is not there

Comment: Show your source tree (i.e. your django source files) in their file hierarchy. There should be a directory named blog. And the directory should have a file named `__init__.py` in it. This question touches on the issue of unfound modules: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1260792/python-import-a-file-from-a-subdirectory/1260846

Comment: I am updating the question with that

Answer (score 1):

You need to put `PYTHONPATH` into the environment supervisord creates to run `./manage.py`, supervisord won't inherit environment variables from wherever you set `PYTHONPATH`.

```
[program:gunicorn]
command = ./manage.py run_gunicorn -w 4 -k gevent
directory = /home/krishna/workspace/django/learn/
user = krishna
autostart = true
autorestart = true
environment=PYTHONPATH="[Your PYTHONPATH goes here]"
stdout_logfile = /var/log/supervisor/gunicorn.log
stderr_logfile = /var/log/supervisor/gunicorn_err.log
```

For more information, check out `environment` in [the docs](http://supervisord.org/configuration.html#program-x-section-settings).

Answer (score 0):

I have a configured a system with a similar setup. I used the `gunicorn_django` wrapper which is installed in the `bin` dir in the virtualenv home dir to start the django project. The wrapper is supplied by gunicorn.

I think this would work for you (just remember to adjust the path to your virtalenv directory):

```
[program:gunicorn]
command=/path/to/virtualenv_dir/bin/gunicorn_django -w 4 -k gevent
directory=/home/krishna/workspace/django/learn/
user=krishna
autostart=true
autorestart=true
stdout_logfile = /var/log/supervisor/gunicorn.log
stderr_logfile = /var/log/supervisor/gunicorn_err.log
```