# Issue With Relative Imports In Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, importerror

I'm running into an issue with how to properly declare imports for some modules that I've written.

Suppose the follow directory structure:

```
main_dir/
 __init__.py
 module_A
    sub_dir/
     __init__.py
     module_B
     module_C
```

So that modules B and C are both in the same subdirectory relative to module A.

Module B imports C.
Module A sometimes imports B.

So, in Module B, using `import module_C` works fines.

And in Module A, using `import sub_dir.module_C` works fine.

However, in Module A, using `import sub_dir.module_B`
causes an ImportError `no module named 'module_C'` because B imports C.

I'm assuming that I could change B to `import sub_dir.module_C` but I don't want to do that because then it will break when I start directly in B rather than import B from A.

What's the correct way(s) to handle this sort of issue?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Python: import a file from a subdirectory](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1260792/python-import-a-file-from-a-subdirectory)

Comment: main_dir already has an __init__.py file. Does sub_dir need one as well?

Comment: Yes. And fix  your code example showing it has an `__init__.py`, or we don't know you've done it

Comment: @MauroBaraldi tried adding an __init__.py to sub_dir as well, it did not resolve the issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should be your app structure of files.

```
app/
├── __init__.py
├── module_a.py
└── subdir
    ├── __init__.py
    ├── module_b.py
    └── module_c.py
```

**module_a.py**

```
from subdir import module_b, module_c
```

Then, you will have access to all modules from **module_a**.

If you import **module_b** in **module_c** or **module_c** in **module_b** you will have an [cyclic import](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/744373/circular-or-cyclic-imports-in-python) issue. This is a design question. You need to review your code and rethink how to link modules.

Comment: I was hoping there would be an alternative to restructuring the modules, as the current structure fits well with the my mental construct of how they are related to each other and the way I use them. Unfortunately, that particular model does not seem to fit well with Python's expectations, so I shall have to adjust my own practices rather than fight a losing battle with the language. Thanks for your help.

Comment: I don't know which framework you're using to build your application, but this doc [building large apps with Flask](https://github.com/mitsuhiko/flask/wiki/Large-app-how-to) could help you with other issues like this. ;-)