# import a module in current working directory

Tags: python

I have following directory structure,

```
/
  __init__.py
  __meta__.py
```

I tried to import `__meta__` in a file but python complains about not finding a module named `__meta__`. I checked the current working directory for the file useing `os.getcwd()` which printed the directory with `__meta__.py`.

But I can import the module from python interpreter.

Comment: Why is it called `__meta__.py`?

Comment: Take a look at [Issue with relative imports in python](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29287540/issue-with-relative-imports-in-python)

Comment: @jonrsharpe, its a file that contains information about the project. Its just a name :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Append it to sys path first, and then try to import your module

```
import os
import sys
sys.path.append(os.getcwd())
```

Comment: wouldn't it polute the system path?

Comment: to avoid accidently loading a similar module eariler in sys.path use instead: `sys.path.insert(0,os.path.dirname(__file__))`