# Import module from subdirectory of parent directory?

Tags: python

I have the following directory structure:

```
dir1
    myscript.bat
    P1
        __init__.py            
        test1.py
    P2
        __init__.py
        test2.py
```

When running, `module1` needs to import `module2` and I get the following error:

```
no module named P2.
```

`dir1` contains my pydev project and the project runs correctly in pydev.
The error only happens when using batch file.

How can I fix this error?

I have read the documentation mentioned in the comment, but have not been able to solve my error. Below I have the contents of module 1 and 2 and myscript.bat.

test.py:

```
from P2.test2 import test2

def test():
    print(" I am module test")
```

test2.py:

```
def test2():
    print(" I am module test2")
```

myscript.bat

```
set PATH=%PATH%;Python34\DLLs
SET PYTHONPATH=P1;P2
.\python34\python .\P1\test.py
```

Comment: Can you include your import statements please?

Comment: Possible duplicate http://stackoverflow.com/q/1260792/5699807

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Python: import a file from a subdirectory](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1260792/python-import-a-file-from-a-subdirectory)

Comment: Here you read [**_Relative imports for the billionth time_**](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14132789/relative-imports-for-the-billionth-time)?

Comment: Use absolute paths in the `PYTHONPATH`