# How to import a project subfolder so that it is available once the installed project has been imported?

Tags: python, import, python-packaging

How to import a project subfolder so that it is available once a project has been imported?

For example how to import the contents of `project.tools` so that after importing the project using `import project`, `project.tools.common.function()` is available?

```
project
|
|--tools
|  |--__init__.py
|  \--common.py
|
|--__init__.py
|--core.py
\--cli.py
```

I've tried the following:

1. `from . import tools` in `project/__init__.py` and `from . import *` in `project/tools/__init.py` which resulted in: `ImportError: cannot import name 'tools'`.
2. `from .tools import *` in `project/__init__.py` and `from . import *` in `project/tools/__init.py` which resulted in: `ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'project.tools'`.
3. `from .tools import common` in `project/__init__.py` and `from . import *` in `project/tools/__init.py` which resulted in: `ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'project.tools'`.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Import a file from a subdirectory?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1260792/import-a-file-from-a-subdirectory)

Comment: No this is regarding an installable project (which can be imported using `import project`)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `import tools` in your .py script directly. 
Then use `tools.common.function()` in the function call.

When you place **init**.py in your folder, the folder becomes callable. 
Hence you can import that folder and its scripts directly into your scripts.

Answer (score -1):

this will solve your issue

```
import tools.common as COMMON
COMMON.function()
```

Comment: Result: `ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'tools'`

Comment: in which file did you put my code ? this should be put in your main script (core or cli.py)

Comment: `project/__init__.py`

Comment: This should be put in your main script (core or cli.py) '__init__.py' file should pe empty

Comment: `AttributeError: module 'project' has no attribute 'tools'`. `project` is an installable project and not a script/folder

Comment: yes i already use it in one of my projectts and it works perfectly but you have alternative like https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1260792/import-a-file-from-a-subdirectory  + https://ibb.co/hJ5Gu5 loog at controllers.CRUD and you will see that this code is perfectly working.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/153108/discussion-between-cristianr-and-dave).

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/153114/discussion-between-dave-and-cristianr).