# How to import python file in another Flask?

Tags: python, python-2.7, flask

I have an `init.py` file. I have a subdirectory `/controller` in the same path.

I tried to import file `/controller/file.py` inside `init.py` like this:

```
import controller/file
import controller/file.py
```

It does not work. How to do that easy in Flask framework or default in Python?

Comment: These two might help you: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1260792/import-a-file-from-a-subdirectory https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4383571/importing-files-from-different-folder

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Firstly, the files you have to put there are called `__init__.py`. Secondly, you should normally leave these empty, unless you want some very specific behaviour.

Lastly, look at this folder structure

```
- __init__.py
- main.py
+ foo
  - __init__.py
  - foo_app.py
+ bar
  - __init__.py
  - bar_app.py
```

and in `foo_app.py`

```
import bar.bar_app
```

Edit: For this to work, the application has to be started from the parent directory.

Comment: When I tried this I get: `ImportError: No module named controller.file`

Comment: I use this: `import flask.controller.api`

Answer (score 2):

As [@Davidism](https://stackoverflow.com/users/400617/davidism) mentioned in the comments above you would import the files "  The same way you import anywhere else. Import paths are separated by dots, not slashes."

Let's say you have a file structure like this

```
/Project
 --program.py
   /SubDirectory
    --TestModule.py
```

In this example let's say that the contents of `TestModule.py` is:

```python
def printfunction(x):
    print(x)
```

---

Now let's begin first, in your `program.py` you need to `import sys` then add your subdirectory to python's environment paths using this line of code

```python
import sys
sys.path.insert(0, os.getcwd()+"/SubDirectory")
```

Now you can import the module as normal. Continuing with the file structure described above you would now import the module like so

```python
import TestModule
```

You can now call the function `printfunction()` from the `TestModule.py` file just like normal

```python
TestModule.printfunction("This is a test! That was successful!");
```

This should output:

```
This is a test! That was successful!
```

---

All in all your `program.py` file should look like this:

```python
import sys
sys.path.insert(0, os.getcwd()+"/SubDirectory")    
import TestModule
TestModule.printfunction("This is a test! That was successful!");
```