# Proper way of importing Python scripts from separate folders

Tags: python, terminal, pycharm, virtualenv

So I have been fiddling around as well as conducting some serious work with Python for quite some time. Though, I still have some issues with it every once in a while.

I find it to be the most comfortable using `PyCharm CE` when working with Python. The typical scenario is that I just create a new `virtualenv`, launch PyCharm and open up my `virtualenv` there. And from there on out, it's like on auto-pilot, PyCharm handles all the dirty work related to which `site-packages` and Python runtime to use.

I always like to keep my `virtualenv`s clean and organized, so I often find myself semantically organizing my source code into submodules/subfolders. So whenever I want to import some code, or class, or whatever from another folder I just import it.

Imagine I have the following structure in my `virtualenv`:

```
├── bin
├── include    
├── lib           
└── src
    ├── foo.py 
├── important_scripts
    ├── some_script.py
    └── some_other_script.py
└── pip-selfcheck.json
```

Now, somewhere in `foo.py`, I want to use a function named `A()` that is implemented in `some_script.py`. The obvious way would be to add a simple line to `foo.py` - something like `from some_script import A`. Doing such works perfectly when I run and debug my code (`foo.py` in this case) from PyCharm.

As opposed to the the typical scenario I have described above, I wanted to do the same from the `Terminal.app`. So I fire up the Terminal, `cd` to my `virtualenv` and activate it. Then, what I do is, using the Python executable that is under the `bin` folder in my `virtualenv`, I try to run `foo.py` (At least this is what I think is the equivalent of right-clicking and running `foo.py` from the PyCharm window). Unfortunately, I get the error `ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'some_script'`.

I think I am missing a simple detail or something. Because like I said, it works like magic when run from PyCharm.

Anyways, any advice or help will be highly appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: See [Import a file from a subdirectory?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1260792/import-a-file-from-a-subdirectory)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for all the responses and references to possible solutions. While researching online, I have come across various instances of more or less the same problem that people were having while importing modules and packages. So, this is how I have just resolved it:

- Under the `important_scripts` directory, I have included a file named `__init__.py`. This basically just tells the Python interpreter that this is indeed a Python package, rather than an ordinary subdirectory.
- In this `__init__.py`, I have added in the line

  ```
  from important_scripts.some_script import A
  ```
- Then in the script, from which I will be importing the function `A`, that is, `foo.py` I have included the following lines:

  ```
  import os
  import sys
  sys.path.append(os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(__file__)))
  ```

  which basically appends the `virtualenv` into the `site-packages`.