# Importing method from another python class

Tags: python

I was having some problem when trying to import method from another python class. I am following [this guide](https://github.com/jfkirk/tensorrec). When I tried to run the attention.py, I am getting this error message:

```
File "D:\Desktop\tensorrec-master\examples\attention_example.py", line 8, in <module>
from test.datasets import get_movielens_100k
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'test.datasets'
```

I even tried to change the import statement to:

```
import test.datasets.py
test.datasets.get_movielens_100k(negative_value=0)
```

But I am still getting the same error message. Any ideas? Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Project structure needs to be known to your Python interpreter. And how to do it?

Set PYTHONPATH to base directory of your project
Add **init**.py file in each directory

Voila! You will be able to import from any directory under your base folder after that

Comment: Sorry but what do you mean? You mean to set it at the environment variables?

Comment: Yes PYTHONPATH is the env variable. More on init file here http://mikegrouchy.com/blog/2012/05/be-pythonic-__init__py.html

Answer (score 1):

From [Import a file from a subdirectory?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1260792/import-a-file-from-a-subdirectory) :

> In short, you need to put a blank file named
>
> ```
> __init__.py
> ```
>
> in the "lib" directory.