# How to import a file from a subdirectory in python from a subpackage in another directory?

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-import

I have the following directory structure in my home projects folder.

```
 |ALL-IN-ONE
    |demo
         |__init__.py
         |__main__.py
    |models
         |grpc
             |allinone_server.py
```

And I want to import from allinone_server.py a function defined in **main**.py called images_demo. I have tried

```
from demo.__main__ import images_demo
```

It is not working. How can I import it? The function I am trying to import is located inside **main**.py which is inside demo directory. I am trying to import it from the file allinone_server.py in grpc. I guess I have made my question clear now.
Here is the whole tree for the project

```
├── demo
│   ├── __init__.py
│   ├── __main__.py
│   └── __pycache__
│       ├── __init__.cpython-36.pyc
│       └── main.cpython-36.pyc
├── description
├── environment.yml
├── HEAD
├── hooks
│   ├── applypatch-msg.sample
│   ├── commit-msg.sample
│   ├── fsmonitor-watchman.sample
│   ├── post-update.sample
│   ├── pre-applypatch.sample
│   ├── pre-commit.sample
│   ├── prepare-commit-msg.sample
│   ├── pre-push.sample
│   ├── pre-rebase.sample
│   ├── pre-receive.sample
│   └── update.sample
├── imgs
│   └── 44.jpg
├── info
│   └── exclude
├── __init__.py
├── loggers
│   ├── __init__.py
│   └── __pycache__
│       └── __init__.cpython-36.pyc
├── models
│   ├── adience_large1.h5
│   ├── adience_small1.h5
│   ├── AgeModel.json
│   ├── detection_age_gender_large1.h5
│   ├── detection_age_gender_small1.h5
│   ├── detection_age_gender_smile_large1.h5
│   ├── detection_age_gender_smile_small1.h5
│   ├── detection_age_large1.h5
│   ├── detection_age_small1.h5
│   ├── detection_large1.h5
│   ├── detection_small1.h5
│   ├── grpc
│   │   ├── adele_2016.jpg
│   │   ├── allinone_client.py
│   │   ├── all_in_one_pb2_grpc.py
│   │   ├── all_in_one_pb2.py
│   │   ├── all_in_one.proto
│   │   ├── allinone_server.py
│   │   ├── benedict_cumberbatch_2014.png
│   │   ├── cat.png
│   │   ├── classroom_in_tanzania.jpg
│   │   ├── decoded1.py
│   │   ├── decoded.py
│   │   ├── elon_musk_2015.jpg
│   │   ├── laos.jpg
│   │   ├── model_face.jpg
│   │   ├── __pycache__
│   │   │   ├── all_in_one_pb2.cpython-36.pyc
│   │   │   ├── all_in_one_pb2_grpc.cpython-36.pyc
│   │   │   └── decoded.cpython-36.pyc
│   │   ├── sophia.jpg
│   │   ├── test
│   │   │   ├── __init__.py
│   │   │   ├── __pycache__
│   │   │   │   └── __init__.cpython-36.pyc
│   │   │   └── test_images
│   │   │       ├── adele_2016.jpg
│   │   │       ├── benedict_cumberbatch_2014.png
│   │   │       ├── classroom_in_tanzania.jpg
│   │   │       ├── elon_musk_2015.jpg
│   │   │       ├── __init__.py
│   │   │       ├── laos.jpg
│   │   │       ├── model_face.jpg
│   │   │       ├── sophia.jpg
│   │   │       ├── waaah.jpg
│   │   │       ├── woman.jpg
│   │   │       └── zebra_stripes.jpg
│   │   ├── waaah.jpg
│   │   ├── woman.jpg
│   │   └── zebra_stripes.jpg
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Import a file from a subdirectory?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1260792/import-a-file-from-a-subdirectory)

Answer (score 1):

So you've referred to main.py, but you also have __main__.py in your directory structure.  I'll assume that your directory actually contains main.py instead of __main__.py.

To import from levels up in a package, start your import with a period.
To import just one function you would use `from .main import images_demo`

Now, let's start by saying main.py is in grpc/ along with allinone_server.py, then we'll move it to different directories and see how the import changes.

If it were in grpc/ `from .main import images_demo`

If it were in models/ `from ..main import images_demo`

If it were in __ALL-IN-ONE/ `from ...main import images_demo`

If it were in __demo/ `from ...__demo.main import images_demo`

Every extra period brings you up one level in the hierarchy, then you use the name of the next level down in the target path until you reach where you want to be.

Now let's suppose you wanted to import the whole of main.py.
If it were in grpc/ `from . import main`

If it were in models/ `from .. import main`

If it were in __ALL-IN-One/ `from ... import main`

If it were in __demo/ `from ...__demo import main`

Finally, the dot notation to move up a level only works if the file that uses it is in a package, so this will work fine if at the top level you start your program in a scope outside of this package then use `from __ALL-IN-ONE.models.grpc import allinone_server`

However, if you run `allinone_server.py` directly then it will fail to import anything above it as it isn't being imported as part of a package.  Try that out, and let me know if that needs better explanation.

Good luck!

Comment: I tried `from ...__demo.main import images_demo` but I couldn't import the  module. It is saying `ValueError: attempted relative import beyond top-level package`

Comment: So that's what happens when you run your file from inside the package, can you comment exactly how you tried to run it?

Comment: I tried to run it from grpc folder using the command `python allinone_server.py` Should I go one directory up and run it?

Comment: That's the problem, it's what I was trying to describe in my last paragraph but wasn't sure how to word it well, I'll rephrase once we have it working.  That's happened because if you run the file directly python doesn't know it is part of a package.  Try going to the directory __ABOVE__ ALL-IN-ONE then running `python -c "from ALL-IN-ONE.models.grpc import allinone_server"`  There's going to be one more problem here, which is that you can't have a dash in a python name (it would try to do ALL minus IN minus ONE), so rename that to use underscores instead.

Comment: In fact, one more question, are you wanting all of these files to be part of the same package, called ALL_IN_ONE? Or is your package called demo and the models/grpc/allinone_server.py tree a separate thing?

Comment: What I am using right now is trying to copying the file demo into models/grpc and then `from demo.main import images_demo, video_demo, process_video, webcam_demo, video_demo
` by renaming __main__.py to main.py It is working but when I make them in separate directories  none of the commands to import the main module are not working. This means it is not going one directory up when I use from .demo and from ..demo

Answer (score 1):

You can't import a function from another folder directly and for that you have to use this:

```
import sys
sys.path.insert(0, "../../demo/")
```

Another step is to rename `__main__` to `main`.

here is the exact example that worked for me:

**The tree:**

```
.
├── demo
│   ├── __init__.py
│   ├── main.py
│   
└── models
    └── grpc
        └── allinone_server.py
```

**main.py:**

```
def images_demo():
    print("hello there")
```

**The calling file**(`allinone_server.py`)**:**

```
import sys
sys.path.insert(0, "../../demo/")

import main

main.images_demo()
```

Comment: How do I import a function defined inside `demo/__main__.py` named `images_demo()`? not the main module?

Comment: I renamed the function to `images_demo()` to sweet you need.

Comment: I renamed the file __main__.py to main.py and added the line `import main`. When I try to call the function as `main.images_demo()` it says            `File "allinone_server.py", line 25, in <module>
    import main
  File "../../demo/main.py", line 1, in <module>
    from demo import load_model,get_layer,selective_search_demo
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'demo'                                        `

Comment: copy and paste the example I provided and try it, and be sure that you are in `grpc` folder.

Comment: Yeah it works but couldn't get it done in my project. May be the tree of the directory structure could help if you take a llook at it.

Comment: I used exactly your directory tree to avoid conflicts, I think you should give us your code in the question you asked to be clear.

Comment: got it fixed by copying the whole demo directory in the grpc folder which I donot recommend but .s and ..s are not working They are not gonig up the hierarchy from the current directory.