# Importing file from local sub-folder

Tags: python, python-3.6

I am importing a python file that resides in a local sub-folder. But I get the below error upon trying to import:

> ImportError: cannot import name 'Conf' from 'subfolder.utils'

Does this error mean it cannot find the python file I am trying to import? Or does it mean the file I am trying to import has errors in it? How do I resolve this error?

My folder structure is:

```
src/   
  __init__.py
  main.py   
  subfolder/ 
    __init__.py 
    utils/  
      __init__.py
      conf.py
```

main.py:

```
from subfolder.utils import Conf
```

conf.py:

```
class Conf:
   ....
```

*I am using python 3.6

Comment: You got answer here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1260792/import-a-file-from-a-subdirectory

Answer (score 2):

**You need to mention the module name i.e. `conf.py` in the import.**

So, you can effectively do `from subfolder.utils.conf import Conf`

Alternatively, you can import the `Conf` in `utils/__init__.py` and your imports should work just fine.