# Python 3.x multi level imports

Tags: python-3.x

I am converting to new style relative imports in Python 3.x.  I am currently getting the error below when I try to perform an import from File1.py to utilsx.py

```
ValueError: Attempted relative import in non-package
```

I have the below folder structure.  A project called MySuite contains all the tests in tests folder which is in the MySuite Project.  These tests depend on certain utilities that exist in the utils project.

```
└── project
    ├── utils
    │   ├── utils1.py
    │   └── utils2.py
    └── MySuite
        ├── Runner.py
        └── Tests
            └── File1.py
            └── File2.py
            └── File3.py
```

The import statement that I am attempting to use from File1 is:

```
from .utils.utils1 import *
```

I also tried:

```
from ..utils.utils1 import *
```

While I only expect one of them to work neither do!  Any ideas to
change syntax or maybe I forgot something?

Comment: does this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1260792/import-a-file-from-a-subdirectory helps?

Comment: A question from 10 years ago uses the old style relative imports.  I'm trying to use the new path support in 3.x. Although I had mentioned Python 3 already I made my first sentence more clear.

Comment: @napuzba  Interesting read but it doesn't resolve my up 2 directories and over issue.  Only the projects are checked in (utils and MySuite).  MySuite depends on the utils project but are not contained together as a project.  The additional containing folder doesn't exist and cannot be in this case. :( I'm still looking for a solution.  Just as another note these two projects are owned by different owners.

Answer (score 0):

Don't use any "." before utils.Like you can do

```
from utils.utils1 import *
```

Comment: Removing the . returns: No module named fmsPythonUtilities.TestInfo

Comment: try doing something like this.
    export PYTHONPATH="${PYTHONPATH}:/path/to/your/module/"
or add the "utils" package to your python's dist-packages/side-packages.

Comment: Your last comment is the old pre Python 3 technique that I'm trying to get rid of.  To move to a more standard Python 3 configuration.  Little lost why the Python team didn't do other standard language support for paths with import.  All I 'should' have to do is something like: 

from ../../utils/utils1 import * 

I understand I'm mixing Python and C++ style coding but it's just to get the idea across. I don't believe anybody would have gotten lost.  I do see a bunch of confusion on this topic.