# Importing function from another cog with discord.py

Tags: python, class, discord, discord.py

I would like to import some functions from another cog so they can be used for several cogs in different .py files. How would I go about doing that? Here's what the documentation says:

```
class Economy(commands.Cog):
    ...

    async def withdraw_money(self, member, money):
        # implementation here
        ...

    async def deposit_money(self, member, money):
        # implementation here
        ...

class Gambling(commands.Cog):
    def __init__(self, bot):
        self.bot = bot

    def coinflip(self):
        return random.randint(0, 1)

    @commands.command()
    async def gamble(self, ctx, money: int):
        """Gambles some money."""
        economy = self.bot.get_cog('Economy')
        if economy is not None:
            await economy.withdraw_money(ctx.author, money)
            if self.coinflip() == 1:
                await economy.deposit_money(ctx.author, money * 1.5)
```

as an example, but that means I have to define `economy` every time if I would like to call on it. Is there a more efficient method for calling a function in another cog?

Comment: Assuming the file is called `cog.py`, you can try using `from cog import Economy` in the file you want to use `Economy` again

Comment: The file isn't named cog.py, it's in a folder called cogs, structured like this:

main.py


cogs -> cog files here

Comment: Try this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1260792/import-a-file-from-a-subdirectory with the above

Comment: Importing `Economy` itself won't work as is, since `withdraw_money` and `deposit_money` are instance methods, and initializing another version of the cog would definitely be a lot less efficient than simply getting the existing one with `Bot.get_cog`.

Comment: You could try setting `economy` in `Gambling.__init__`.  That would make the order in which you load cogs meaningful, and you would need to add logic to handle reloads if that's possible in your code.

Answer (score 1):

If `withdraw_money` and `deposit_money` don't use any of `Economy`'s attributes or methods, you could make them static methods and import `Economy` to use them or just make them functions outside the class/cog and import them directly.

Otherwise, you can look for a way to refactor those methods so that they don't rely on `Economy` so that you can make them static methods or independent functions.

If that's not possible, this is already the best way to do it.
`Bot.get_cog` is O(1) anyway, so there's very minimal impact efficiency-wise.