# Error when trying to load a file A in file B when importing file B from file C

Tags: python-3.x

This is my dir structure

-C/

---C.py

-B/

---B.py - reads and prints contents of another_folder/A.txt

---another_folder/

------A.txt

i  need to import B.py in C.py

but even if i change the sys.path i.e sys.path.insert('../B'), 
it doesn’t read the another_folder/A.txt and throws an error

any ideas? or am i doing something fundamentally wrong?

Comment: Where is your empty `__init__.py` file? It would help it resolve the scope :) -> https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1260792/import-a-file-from-a-subdirectory

Comment: Hello and welcome to SO. You may want to read [ask] and [mcve] and edit your question accordingly.