# ModuleNotFoundError - Cannot import a python file even though python file exists

Tags: python, import, virtualenv, python-import, visual-studio-code

I have a project structure like this:

```
.
├── .venv
|     └── bin
|          └── python
├── config
│     └── conf.py
├── utils
│   └── test.py
└── requirements.txt
```

**Each of the directories above have an __init__.py file so they should be picked up as a Python package**.

I am unable to import config into the utils.test.py script.

**The error I encounter is**:

```
File "./utils/test.py", line 2, in <module>
import config.conf
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'config'
```

My Python path is "./.venv/bin/python".

Can someone help me resolve this issue so I can import files from different sub-directories?

Thanks!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Import a file from a subdirectory?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1260792/import-a-file-from-a-subdirectory)

Answer (score 0):

Add an empty  `__init__.py` file in the config folder.

Then you can do the following in your `test.py`

```
import config.conf as conf

conf.your_config_function()
```

Comment: Hi NIco I already have an empty __init__.py in the config directory, as well as all other directories in the workspace. Is there another reason why I could be experiencing this error?

Answer (score 0):

Add empty `__init__.py` file to the config directory in order to identify it as a python package. See more [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/448271/what-is-init-py-for)

Updating following the comment -
Add the folder path to the system path -

```
import os
import sys
sys.path.insert(0, os.path.dirname(os.getcwd()))
import config.conf
```

Comment: Hi Tom, I already have an empty __init__.py in the config directory, as well as all other directories in the workspace. Is there another reason why I could be experiencing this error?