# How can we go to package inside package when outer package is imported in python

Tags: python

Can anyone help me with a question, if a python package  is imported can we directly import package inside another package in  package?

Lets say a python pkg structure is like:

```
   module
   |__ module1
   |   |__ __init__.py
   |   |__ pyScript1.py
   |   |__ pyScript2.py
   |__ __init__.py
```

Then is a python script if we have a script like `import module` Can we call the pyScript1 using `module.pyScript1` without importing module1?

I know this will work by adding **all** in module > **init**.py file and add the module1 sub packages in it. but when I run `dir(module)` I can see module1 in the list. But I don't want to see module1 in dir list.

Can anyone help with this?

EDIT:

What if instead of 'module1' if we have multiple version modules in 'module' like '1_0_0, 1_1_0, 2_0_0,...etc' and we maintain and environmental variable `MODULE_VERSION=1.1.0` and according to the version specified we need to refer to that particular version module.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Import a file from a subdirectory?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1260792/import-a-file-from-a-subdirectory)

Answer (score 0):

> Then is a python script if we have a script like `import module` Can we
> call the `pyScript1` using `module.pyScript1` without `importing module1`?

The answer, is `dependent` what you have declared to be initialized in the package `__init__.py`. if you import the `pyScript1.py` in the `__init__.py` then the answer `yes` and if no then the answer is `no`.

dunder all `__all__` :

dunder all is good tool for controlling what to export from our module when we got imported (our module not the package).

Comment: What if we don't have __init__.py file in module package...
Currently I'm trying to achive "activating versions for the python packages"
Lets say "module" is a package and we will have multiple version for "module" and we will define an environmental variable saying MODULE_VERSION=1.0.0 and the version number will be specified in the module package. Can we import modules like this?

Comment: what you mean by .."if we don't have init.py file in module package..", you cant import your module or any thing else. python packages is namespace packages. this is a different case and out of you question scope.

Comment: Sorry, I mean if `__init__.py` is there but version module will be dynamic selected according to the environment variable of the version will be changed. How can we go into particular version module dynamically?

Answer (score 0):

inside `module/__init__.py` file write

```
from  .module1 import pyScript1 
__all__ =['pyScript1']
```

Comment: What if we want to use versions instead of "module1" like "1_0_0". Import line won't work as the module doesn't starts with a character. Let's say that we have an environment variable "module_version=1_0_0" how to get the scripts inside version directory...?

Comment: i think this is related to your package setup, and you can assign value as `module_name=<module name>` plus it seems your practice are off from [pep guidelines](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/), you need to improve the structure or share your setup file for more clearlty

Comment: Sorry for in appropriate information. I know that we can't create a module which is starting with numbers. But I'm trying to achieve a way that if we can maintain an environment where other modules may refer the specified version of current module. This way we may work with upgrading the versions and use the python modules. I think you understand the issue

Comment: mabye be common folder with the package name and store version in subdirectories, i gues you need to see how pypi maintain it's python modules