# How do I properly import classes from directory structure like this?

Tags: python, class, oop

I have a Python directory like this, and I am running `main_script.py` from `src`.

Whenever I try to import classes from `class_files` into `main_script.py`, I get an error. How do I properly do that?

```
 - src/
   - jobs/
   - _init_.py
    - my_team/
      - _init_.py
     - my_project/
       - _init_.py
       - main_script.py
      - class_files/
        - class1.py
        - class2.py
        - class3.py
        - __init__.py
```

I already tried doing an absolute import, which also did not work.

`from jobs.my_team.my_project.class_files import *`

Comment: I think the solution to your question is similar to this... https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1260792/import-a-file-from-a-subdirectory

Answer (score 0):

`jobs.my_team.my_project.class_files` would only work if each of those constituent parts is a Python package. Eg,

```
src/
    jobs/
        __init__.py
        my_team/
            __init__.py
            my_project/
                __init__.py
                main_script.py
                class_files/
                    class1.py
                    class2.py
                    class3.py
                    __init__.py
```

Your import tree must be made up of Python packages. If it doesn't have `__init__.py` in it, that directory is not a Python package. Simple as that.

Also, for this to work, your `src/` directory needs to be in the `$PYTHONPATH` environment variable or be added to `sys.path` at runtime.

Comment: I tried adding __init__.py to `src` and everywhere else, but that didn't help. I also did sys.path.insert(0, './src')

Comment: you would only add `__init__.py` to `src` if you want to make `src` a package. And adding a relative path to sys.path isn't going to work; it needs to be absolute.