# How to do directory referral in Python for all scripts in project

Tags: python, python-3.x, subdirectory, referrals

I'm doing Python for some time now, but this is the first time I stage it in a project with different script that refer to each other. The structure of the files is like this (simplified):

```
Project Folder
   |
   |__folder1
         |
         |__Folder1a
               |
               |__script1
         |
         |
         |__folder 1b
               |
               |__script2 
               |
               |__script3
```

So, because script2 and script3 both use functions in script 1, I'm now doing something like this, in both script2 and script3:

```
main_dir = os.path.dirname(os.path.realpath(__file__))
modules_dir = os.path.realpath(os.path.join(main_dir, '..', '..'))
sys.path.insert(0, modules_dir)

from folder1.folder1a.script1 import function1
```

The thing is: This way I need to put this code in every script, which is not very handy. I do have a settings script, so maybe I can put the referal code there. I'm just not sure how to do it in a way that is the most neat and efficient. Could someone help me with this?

Comment: This should help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1260792/import-a-file-from-a-subdirectory