# How to run a python file from inside another python file

Tags: python, python-3.x

website\data

I have these two folders, where data is inside the website folder. In website, I have a file called main.py. I would like this script to run the three other python scripts inside data. How would I do this?

I also have a subfolder within data called reports in which there is a .xlsx excel file. I would also like to launch this after running all three files inside data. How would I do this?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Import a file from a subdirectory?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1260792/import-a-file-from-a-subdirectory)

Answer (score 1):

Question unclear, but you could `import` the content of those files into main.py then execute the content.

Also, you want to "launch" your xlsx file ? or just exec a software that could open it ?