# overriding a function implementation

Tags: python

I have the following files:

```
t.py:  
def foo(): 
    print("foo")

folder/t.py: 
def foo(): 
    print("bar")

folder/main.py: 

import t
if __name__ == "__main__":
  t.foo()
```

when I run it on the command line with `python -m folder.main` it prints `"foo"` but I actually want to import `folder/t.py` so that it prints `"bar"` instead. How can I do that?

Comment: `import folder.t`   https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1260792/import-a-file-from-a-subdirectory

Comment: what folder are you running from? I think that might make the difference here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the following code in `main.py` and run the command `python -m folder.main`.

`sys.path.append()` will add the folder to the system path so that it can find the module `t` in that folder.

```
import sys
sys.path.append('.\\folder\\')

from folder import t
if __name__ == "__main__":
  t.foo()
```

Answer (score 0):

You can import as, so like `import folder.t as ft` then run `ft.foo()`