# Can't access modules of my python package

Tags: python, python-3.x, module, package, sublimetext3

contents of "**init**.py" file inside "handlers" folder:

```
from handlers import client
from handlers import admin
from handlers import other
```

and the content of the "main.py" file looks like this inside the main folder:

```
from aiogram.utils import executor
from datetime import datetime
from create_bot import dp
from handlers import client, admin, other

client.register_handlers_client(dp)
other.register_handlers_other(dp) #last one!

async def on_startup(_):
start_time = datetime.now().strftime("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S")
print("Bot went online at " + start_time)

if __name__ == '__main__':
executor.start_polling(dp, skip_updates=True, on_startup=on_startup)
```

the file structure of my project (this is a telegram bot) looks like this:

```
test_bot ---> __pycache__
     |
     |---> handlers ---> client.py, other.py,__init__.py
     |
     '---> main ---> main.py,config_testbot.py,etc...
```

when running the "main.py" file in cmd it outputs the following:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
    File "main.py", line 5, in <module>
        from handlers import client, admin, other
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'handlers'
```

And so, how to run the file "main.py" without error? How to replace
**from handlers import client, admin, other**
so that everything works without errors?! My python version 3.8.10.
I hope you can help me with this problem, thanks in advance!

Comment: Maybe this is of help to you https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1260792/import-a-file-from-a-subdirectory

Answer (score 0):

TLDR;

```
from handlers.client import *
from handlers.admin import *
from handlers.other import *
```

If I understood correctly, your question is *'How to import a file from a subdirectory'*

I am reading from:

[docs](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/modules.html#packages)

[stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1260792/import-a-file-from-a-subdirectory)

If you are not using **Python 3.3 or upwards** create a blank file called `__init__.py` in the subfolder.

Apparently after **Python 3.3** you no longer need the `__init__.py` file.

And then,

Instead of trying to import *handlers* which I understood to be the *subfolder*, try to import the *file* from the *subfolder* referring to it as

`from subfolder.filename import foo`

in your case:

`from handlers.client import foo`