# Trouble importing file from subdirectory in Django project

Tags: python, django, python-import

I have this file structure in Django project:

```
project
├── app
    └── __init__.py
        views.py
        ...
        tasks
        └── __init__.py
            server_tasks.py
```

In views.py I tried to import project/app/tasks/server_tasks.py by typing following statements

```
from tasks import server_tasks
or
from tasks.server_tasks import *
```

And *python3 manage.py runserver* gives me following output

```
  File "/home/user-unix/python/django_projects/project/app/views.py", line 6, in <module>
    from tasks import server_tasks
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'tasks'
```

How can I import server_tasks.py into views.py?

I tried answers from [very similar question on stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1260792/import-a-file-from-a-subdirectory) but it doesn't work for me.

Comment: If `apps` is treated as a module by Django (I'm not sure of that), then you should be able to add one period to that: `from .tasks import server_tasks`.

Comment: @tim-roberts It gives me following output:  `ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'app.tasks.models'`

Comment: Where did `models` come from?  That's not in your description.  The fact that it knows about `app.tasks` suggests this is the right road to go down.

Comment: @tim-roberts I added a link to repository containing project in question. I imported some View Classes from `.models` file, but i don't think `models` is the problem here.

Comment: The error says `app.tasks.models`, but `models` is not INSIDE `tasks`, it is at the same level.

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
from app.tasks import server_tasks
```

Also, checked your repo. The server tasks file imports from .models, which is not in the same directory. Change that to

```
from app.models import Asset, AssetPriceHistory
```

Hope this helps.