# Python Module Import Issue with pyproject.toml: Organizing Modules in a Directory

Tags: python, import, module, python-import, pyproject.toml

I'm working on a Python project and trying to organize my modules within a directory structure that includes a subdirectory. I have a `pyproject.toml` file to configure module discovery paths, but I'm experiencing difficulties with importing modules from the subdirectory.

Here's my current directory structure:

```
main_directory/
├── main.py
├── pyproject.toml
└── src/
    └── API/
        ├── fileA.py
        └── fileB.py
```

I have a subdirectory `API` within the `src` directory and two Python files, `fileA.py` and `fileB.py`, in the `API` directory. `fileA.py` imports `fileB.py` and `main.py` imports `fileA.py`.

I tried to add the files into the path by doing this with the `pyproject.toml`:

```
[tool.pytest.ini_options]
python_paths = ["src", "src/API"]
```

Initially, in `main.py`, I attempted to import `fileA` like this:

```py
from fileA import *
```

However, that resulted in import errors, suggesting that Python cannot find the `fileA` module.

```
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'FileA'
```

---

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Import a file from a subdirectory?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1260792/import-a-file-from-a-subdirectory)