# Python doesn't import a file in the same directory

Tags: python, import, module, python-import

So my directory looks something like this: [bleh](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mJUee.png)

the file `CreatePage.py` contains the import statement `from Page import *`
but on running it throws the following error

```
No module named 'Page'
  File "D:\My Stuff\School\CS\ViewModel\CreatePage.py", line 1, in <module>
    from Page import *
  File "D:\My Stuff\School\CS\View.py", line 2, in <module>
    from ViewModel.CreatePage import *
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'Page'
```

ive tried `import Page`, `from ViewModel.Page import *` too, but they dont work either.

What am i doing wrong here?

Comment: What makes you think there is a module named `Page` that can be imported?

Comment: Um, i dont get you question. I have a file named ```Page``` which i need to import in this file

Comment: A file is not the same thing as a module.

Comment: Can you create an __init__.py file in the home directory and try?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Import a file from a subdirectory?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1260792/import-a-file-from-a-subdirectory)

Comment: Yes i get that, the issue is that im importing the same file in other files and that works but this one doesnt. Like in ```View.py``` i have ```from ViewModel.Page import *```

Comment: @Abion47 it doesnt. Also, in my case the file being imported and the file it is being import too are in the same directory.

Comment: @PhantomSucksAtCoding It doesn't matter that they are in the same directory. What matters is that they aren't in the program's working directory and therefore not in the path. The linked question has a lot of different answers on how to add a module in a subdirectory to the path, so most if not all of them should be adequate answers to your question.

Comment: @Abion47 ok i tried the ```sys.path.insert```  thing from the question you linked me to, and now it doesnt throw an error, now it throws the same error but for the following line which is ```from Model import *```

Comment: Is that a single traceback message or a couple of different ones edited together? Those two trace lines seem backwards. What is the top level script being executed? If you run `python3 View.py`, then its parent directory is used for search, so `ViewModel.Page` and `ViewModel.CreatePage` should be valid. To note, `CreatePage.py` would have to `from ViewModel.Page import *`.

Comment: `CreatePage.py` should also be able to use the relative import `from .Page import *`.

Comment: @tdelaney Yes it is a single traceback message. Yes the code is being executed from View.py. Yes ive tried ViewModel.Page and it doesnt work either.

Comment: Are you running on the command line? Most recent call last, so that traceback shows ViewModel\CreatePage.py causing View.py to run which is backwards. It may help to post the scripts at this point.

Answer (score 0):

I can reproduce something similar with

*View.py*

```
from ViewModel.CreatePage import *
```

*ViewModel/CreatePage.py*

```
from Page import *
```

*ViewModel/Page.py*

```
print("Page")
```

Run as: `python3 View.py`

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/td/tmp/a/test/View.py", line 1, in <module>
    from ViewModel.CreatePage import *
  File "/home/td/tmp/a/test/ViewModel/CreatePage.py", line 1, in <module>
    from Page import *
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'Page'
```

That is fixed by changing ViewModel/CreatePage.py to a relative import

```
from .Page import *
```

Running again

```
Page
```

running `View.py` as the top level script adds its parent directory to the python module search path. Subdirectories like `ViewModel` are now packages for `View.py` and package-relative imports start working.