How to dynamically import functions from a file in a subdirectory?
I am trying to dynamically import functions from a file in a subdirectory.
For example:
workspace
--|main.py
----|subfolder1
------|subfolder2
--------|file1.py
--------|file2.py

The file main.py would dynamically run a function in file1.py or file2.py. The function in the 2 files are different contents but the same name, I'll call it run for this example.
I am trying to do this so I can have the user input a file they want to run and it will run. The main reason why I chose dynamic imports is because I will be adding files to the list of available files to run every day and I don't want to have or add to a large if statement.
I'm trying to use the importlib module to dynamically import this.
# main.py

file = input("Either file1 or file2")
try:
    mod = importlib.import_module(f"subfolder1.subfolder2.{file}")
except Exception as error:
    print(f"[ERROR] {error}!")
else:
    mod.run()

The error I get is

[ERROR] No module named 'subfolder1.subfolder2.file1.py'; 'subfolder1.subfolder2.file1' is not a package!


https://stackoverflow.com/a/1260813/2834978

@LMC The __init__.py requirement is not applicable for Python-3.x.

@metatoaster It's still applicable according to the docs

@LMC I have added empty __init__.py files to each subdirectory but it still does not work. The error is still the same.

@LMC Much less applicable because of the existence of namespace packages, see https://peps.python.org/pep-0420/, and that the problem here has to do with the code not being set up as a proper package that can be imported normally.

@GalaxyGamerYT You should follow the packaging tutorial to figure out how packages work and from there it should show you how to make imports work.

From python3.11 docs mentioned above: The __init__.py files are required to make Python treat directories containing the file as packages (unless using a namespace package, a relatively advanced feature). Kind of mutually exclusive but both ways are valid.

The KEY POINT that usually causes this question is that Python does not start looking in the folder that contains the script.  It starts looking in the "current directory".  If you run python workspace/main.py for example, then the "current directory" is the one containing workspace, not the one containing main.py.  You can certainly have main.py do sys.path.append( os.path.abspath( os.path.dirname( __file__ ) + '/..' )).

@TimRoberts This isn't the issue, I'm using VSCode and the workspace in the example folder layout is the VSCode workspace which it runs from. Therefore main.py is in the directory the "current directory".

Doh, just read the error message carefully: the problem is you're importing subfolder1.subfolder2.file1.py instead of subfolder1.subfolder2.file1: you're asking for file or module py inside package file1. Strip the extension before importing and it will work.

If you just type file1 or file2 at the prompt, and create the empty __init__.py files, then your program works, at least on my machine.

@joanis Perfect, this solved my issue. It's always the little things rather than the big things that get me. Thank you.

Glad it helped. Took me a while to spot it, but then tada! it was clear.

@joanis Yeah, it made sense after you mentioned it as I'm gathering the file names form os.listdir, so the file names have the extension aswell. I've posted an answer to the original question incase anyone is searching for the answer.

I have fixed my issue, it turns out it was what I was inputting into the importlib.import_module.
The answer to the question tho, should be adding __init__.py files into the directories that will be packages. The __init__.py files are fine being empty but can have contents within.
Helpful links

stackoverflow.com/a/1260813/2834978

Thank you @joanis for the solution to my problem and thank you to everyone else who helped for the solution to the original question.

If you find another question that asks and has answers to your question, you should either delete or self-close your question as a duplicate of that one, not post an answer that essentially just links to another answer.

Read your error message carefully-
[ERROR] No module named 'subfolder1.subfolder2.file1.py'; 'subfolder1.subfolder2.file1' is not a package!

This happened because you called importlib like this-
importlib.import_module("subfolder1.subfolder2.file1.py")

What is confusing you- import_module is NOT looking for a file. It is looking for a module - using a dotted path expression. This is saying "look for a package called subfolder1, with a subpackage called subfolder2, with a subpackage called file1, with a module called py"
When you issue that command, python will search every directory in your sys.path for a package named subfolder1, and then try to import subfolder2.file1.py from it.
the question with "init.py" is that python treats those a bit differently. Imagine your PYTHONPATH included two folders- first and second (in that order). you have a file called second/package/module.py, and an empty folder called first/package. If you do NOT have init.py file in first/package python will NOT consider first/package as a package, and will continue searching and allow you to import package.module from second. If you DO have the __init__.py file in first/package, import package.module will fail.
When you try to import something, your search path is important- you have to make sure that for any dotted name "a.b", that the directory that "a" lives in is on your PYTHONPATH (sys.path). You can modify sys.path at runtime to make that happen.
Ultimately though, the reason your code didn't work is that you included .py in the import name. If your user wants you to import somepackage/somefile.py your import command is somepacakge.somefile (with no .py)
For your specific case (wanting to import random files) you are probably better off NOT including __init__.py files. In fact, your best bet is likely something like this-
import sys
from importlib import Path
target_file = Path("somepath/somefile.py")
target_path = str(target_file.parent)
# ensure the directory your file lives in is first
# on the search path
sys.path.insert(0, target_path)
# import your target file
importlib.import_module(target.stem)
# restore the search path to its previous state
sys.path.pop(0)

(worth mentioning- its rather undefined what happens stuff your target files are trying to import)
