# How to import module when module name has a '-' dash or hyphen in it?

Tags: python, import, module

I want to import `foo-bar.py`, this works:

```py
foobar = __import__("foo-bar")
```

This does not:

```py
from "foo-bar" import *
```

My question: Is there any way that I can use the above format i.e., `from "foo-bar" import *` to import a module that has a `-` in it?

Comment: Why do you have a module with a dash in its name?

Comment: I'm guessing it was originally written as a script rather than as a module.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Python Module with a dash, or hyphen (-) in its name](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7583652/python-module-with-a-dash-or-hyphen-in-its-name)

Comment: @MattiVirkkunen makepy.py of win32com will generate module with dash in it. too bad. comtypes solved this by converting it to underscore

Comment: @MattiVirkkunen I think Python should not limit the names I can give my directories. It is not its responsibility to do so.

Comment: @Zelphir: Do you also think Python should not limit the names you can give your variables and other identifiers? Surely you can see why it's silly to name a module (whose name is defined by the directory name) something that's not a valid identifier.

Comment: @MattiVirkkunen Actually I think variables are something inside Python and thus its "task" to care for, so that's OK. But maybe you have a point there about modules being its part as well. Anyway, it's not a big issue, just something one needs to know : )

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is it ok to use dashes in Python files when trying to import them?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/761519/is-it-ok-to-use-dashes-in-python-files-when-trying-to-import-them)

Answer (score 149, accepted):

In **Python 2**, you can't.  `foo-bar` is not an identifier.  rename the file to `foo_bar.py`

---

It's possible since **Python 3.1+**, see [Julien's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53516983/4298200).

---

If `import` is not your goal (as in: you don't care what happens with `sys.modules`, you don't need it to import itself), just getting all of the file's globals into your own scope, you can use `execfile`

```
# contents of foo-bar.py
baz = 'quux'
```

```
>>> execfile('foo-bar.py')
>>> baz
'quux'
>>>
```

Comment: Python 3.x [What’s New In Python 3.0](https://docs.python.org/3/whatsnew/3.0.html) Removed execfile(). Instead of `execfile(fn)` use `exec(open(fn).read())` Also there is package importlib.

Comment: "*if you don't care what happens with sys.modules*", can you clarify what you meant? What is the condition for using `execfile`?

Comment: `__name__ == "__main__" ` is True when `execfile()`

Answer (score 249):

Starting from Python 3.1, you can use importlib :

```
import importlib  
foobar = importlib.import_module("foo-bar")
```

( https://docs.python.org/3/library/importlib.html )

Comment: I think this is the best solution, especially now that Python 2 is formally deprecated

Comment: how can I rename the module in this way?

Comment: @AliKhosro it will be named whatever variables you set it to. So if you use `helloworld = importlib.import_module("foo-bar")`, then you will reference fields in foo-bar using `helloworld`, e.g. `helloworld.abc`

Answer (score 141):

**Solution**: If you can't rename the module to match Python naming conventions, create a new module to act as an intermediary:

New module `foo_proxy.py`:

```
 tmp = __import__('foo-bar')
 globals().update(vars(tmp))
```

Module doing the import `main.py`:

```
 from foo_proxy import *
```

Comment: I would never implement this. But I can't not give +1 for the sheer brilliance of this hack

Comment: you could actually do this without the `foo_proxy.py` file,  assign the output of `__import__(...)` to `sys.modules['foo_proxy']`.  Actually, don't do that, it's a terrible idea.

Comment: Cool just what I was looking for. There is a usecase, if one uses native libraries which are shipped with a distribution.

Answer (score 58):

If you can't rename the original file, you could also use a symlink:

```
ln -s foo-bar.py foo_bar.py
```

Then you can just do:

```
from foo_bar import *
```

Comment: Doesn't work with Windows unfortunately.

Comment: The *nix command above likely will not, but Windows _does_ have its own symlink support (since Win7): `mklink Link Target` ref: https://www.howtogeek.com/howto/16226/complete-guide-to-symbolic-links-symlinks-on-windows-or-linux/

Answer (score 12):

Like other said you can't use a `-` in python naming, there are many workarounds, one such workaround which would be useful if you had to add multiple modules from a path is using `sys.path`

For example if your structure is like this:

```
foo-bar
├── barfoo.py
└── __init__.py
```

```py
import sys
sys.path.append('foo-bar')

import barfoo
```

Answer (score 2):

This was my scenario: I have a python library cloned in a git submodule which has a dash in its name:

```
|- python-my-lib
| `- mylib.py
`- my-script.py
```

It took me a long time to figure out the equivalent of:

```py
# Do NOT use this!
sys.path.insert(1, './my-lib')
from mylib import MyClass
```

Appending the path is not an option, as it would only work if you run the script within the same directory. If you do `/home/user/bin/my-script.py`, this will fail.

This is the solution:

```py
import importlib
mylib_module = importlib.import_module("python-my-lib.mylib")
MyClass = mylib_module.MyClass
```

Feel free to further improve this solution, if you know a simpler solution.

Answer (score 2):

Python has issues with dash `-`. So use `importlib` instead.
You can run your test scripts just like this -

```
# importlib, because python has issues with dash '-' in module names
import importlib
img2txt = importlib.import_module("img2txt-textextractor")

event_with_txt = {...}

event_with_no_txt = {...}


def test_no_text():
    response = img2txt.handler(event=event_with_txt, context='')
    assert response["body"] == '"Detect Me If You Can. "'

def test_detected_text():
    response = img2txt.handler(event=event_with_no_txt, context='')
    assert response["body"] == '"unable to find anything"'
```

Name your test code as `test_someName.py`. To run, from the same directory on terminal type -

```
pytest
```

Answer (score 0):

in Python 3.6
I had the same problem "`invalid syntax`" when directly

```
import 'jaro-winkler' as jw
```

said
"`No module named 'jaro-winkler'`" when using:

```
jw = __import__('jaro-winkler')
```

and `importlib.import_module()` same.

finally i use pip uninstall the `jaro-winkler` module...just FYI