# calling a function that lives in a sibling folder from the script folder

Tags: python

I am trying to call a function that live in a sibling folder from the script that I run:

in *folder-B/B.py*:

```
def methodB():
    return "\n\nThis is methodB from Folder-B"
```

in *folderA/A.py*:

```
import sys
sys.path.append("..")
from folder-B.B import methodB
s = methodB()
print(s)
```

When calling
python A.py

I get error:

> File "A.py", line 3
> from folder-B.B import methodB
> ^ SyntaxError: invalid syntax

*folderA* and *folder-B* are at the same folder level.

I know the problem comes from the dash, but I could not find any solution to keep the folder name with a dash

Any idea ?

Comment: Have a look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8350853/how-to-import-module-when-module-name-has-a-dash-or-hyphen-in-it

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to import module when module name has a '-' dash or hyphen in it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8350853/how-to-import-module-when-module-name-has-a-dash-or-hyphen-in-it)

Comment: As an aside, the two `\n`:s at the beginning of your string look like a mistake, probably more on the design side.