# How to import polars-lts-cpu correctly

Tags: python, python-polars

I would like to use the python package [polars-lts-cpu](https://pypi.org/project/polars-lts-cpu/), since I am facing some hardware issues on a gitlab runner. How do I import this package in Python, i.e. what is the alias?

A simple `import polars-lts-cpu` yields a syntax error. The documentation does not give any hints or suggestions.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Hi, thank you for your quick answer. Maybe I did not understand this correctly: Is it just a supplementary package and is not used without `polars` itself and therefore not imported?

Comment: Okay. The documentation is identical to the one of the actual [polars](https://pypi.org/project/polars/) package as far as I can see. So the examples provided there might not be correct for polars-lts-cpu.

Comment: I tried `import polars` already which did not help.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to import module when module name has a '-' dash or hyphen in it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8350853/how-to-import-module-when-module-name-has-a-dash-or-hyphen-in-it)

Comment: Thanks for the hint! Unfortunately, the provided solutions there do not solve my problem, I receive a `ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'polars-lts-cpu'` .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Usage is exactly the same as with the default polars package. So you import `polars`, not `polars-lts-cpu`.

```bash
me:~: $ pip install -U polars-lts-cpu
Collecting polars-lts-cpu
  Downloading polars_lts_cpu-0.15.7-cp37-abi3-manylinux_2_17_x86_64.manylinux2014_x86_64.whl (14.6 MB)
     |████████████████████████████████| 14.6 MB 11.7 MB/s 
me:~: $ python -c "import polars as pl; print(pl.__version__)"
0.15.7
```

Comment: I too suggested this in a comment based on the documentation that op linked, but apparently it didn't work for op https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74856814/how-to-import-polars-lts-cpu-correctly#comment132107135_74856814

Comment: Maybe he must uninstall the the other polars binary. I just created a new environment and can confirm it works.

Comment: Hi everyone, I uninstalled polars and tried to use polats-lts-cpu instead, without changing any mport code, and got a ModuleNotFoundError. I will have another look into this, thanks for the hint.

Comment: Recreating the venv and reinstalling polars-lts-cpu solved the problem, I can import it now via `import polars` as @ritchie46 suggested. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Fwiw, I'm using `poetry` and had a weird behavior.  The upvoted answer is correct, but in my situation incomplete.

The correct process:

```
poetry remove polars
poetry add polars-lts-cpu
poetry shell
python
import polars
```

I did that but still got the error, so there was some residual memory of polars (I think because I originally had them both packages installed).  To fix this I did:

```
poetry shell
pip uninstall polars
pip install polars-lts-cpu
```