# How to install and load polars in Python?

Tags: python, python-polars

Based on [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/74859637/2829961) stackoverflow answer, I installed `polars-lts-cpu` after uninstalling `polars` but I can't get it to work:

[image]

How do I import `polars-lts-cpu`?

### Edit:

I tried the suggestion in the comment but got the same issue:

```
(homl3) C:\Users\umair>python -m pip install polars-lts-cpu
Requirement already satisfied: polars-lts-cpu in c:\users\umair\anaconda3\envs\homl3\lib\site-packages (0.20.5)

(homl3) C:\Users\umair>python
Python 3.10.10 | packaged by conda-forge | (main, Mar 24 2023, 20:00:38) [MSC v.1934 64 bit (AMD64)] on win32
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import polars as pl
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'polars'
```

Comment: please post this **as text**. In any case, it looks like the `pip` is pointing to another Python installation of yours. You could use `python -m pip install polars-lts-cpu` to make sure it is the `piip` associataed with the `python` you have in the path

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga I tried that but did not work. Same issue.

Comment: what does `which python` give you?

Comment: `'which' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.`

Comment: Try to import the library in an anaconda environment, over the anaconda GUI, if you have that. Because your local python interpreter is not looking for packages in: `c:\users\umair\anaconda3\envs\homl3\lib\site-packages`

Comment: @adkop `homl3` env is created with anaconda and the lines under the edit in my question show the result from the terminal opened from anaconda GUI.

Comment: I just installed python outside of anaconda (version 3.12), then installed `polars-lts-cpu` and did `import polars`, and it worked! That means anaconda is the culprit. Thanks for everyone who took the time to read my question and comment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about to use the [conda](https://docs.conda.io/en/latest/) python environment?
It supports independent package, dependency, and environment management for each project.

A couple of benefits

**Package Management**: Conda simplifies the process of installing, updating, and managing packages. It supports both Python and non-Python packages, allowing for a more comprehensive environment setup.

**Platform Independence**: Conda environments are platform-independent, meaning they can be created and used across different operating systems (Windows, macOS, Linux)

It will address your global Python environment.

I will demo for your 'polars-lts-cpu' install problem

Steps

##### Install Conda

download and install from [here](https://www.anaconda.com/download/)

##### Create demo environment

launching Conda prompt

[image]

Format
conda create -n

Run this command from it

```
conda create -n demo_homl3
```

[image]

##### Install python and dependencies

Switch into your demo environment

```
conda activate demo_homl3
```

Then install specific python version and dependencies

```
conda install python=3.10.10 polars-lts-cpu polars
```

[image]

Save this demo python code

Save as `demo.py`. It copy from [here](https://docs.pola.rs/user-guide/basics/reading-writing/)

```
import polars as pl
from datetime import datetime

df = pl.DataFrame(
    {
        "integer": [1, 2, 3],
        "date": [
            datetime(2022, 1, 1),
            datetime(2022, 1, 2),
            datetime(2022, 1, 3),
        ],
        "float": [4.0, 5.0, 6.0],
    }
)

print(df)
```

Result

[image]

[Here](https://conda.io/projects/conda/en/latest/user-guide/getting-started.html#managing-python) is the Conda tutorial.

I think you will like the Conda environment after this experience.

[image: Conda]