# Python - using external API project

Tags: python, git

I want to implement this git package in my project https://github.com/caiomborges/Python-XTB-API

But when try to use first function, according to documentation - import line **from API import XTB** shows an error.

I have Windows 10, Python 3.12.1 and imported websocket-client 1.4.1 and openpyxl 3.0.10 mentioned in documentation.

Steps that have done already:

- My own project is in directory C:\Users\Użytkownik\Desktop\PY_ROBOT\pyrobot
- Clone the repository through CLI (C:\Users\Użytkownik\Desktop\PY_ROBOT\Python-XTB-API)
- Choose directory C:\Users\Użytkownik\Desktop\PY_ROBOT\Python-XTB-API and run in VisualStudioCode Terminal command **python3 -m venv env**
- Run command **.\env\Scripts\activate.ps1** - works fine
- Trying to install with command **pip install .** - generates an error

*ERROR: Directory '.' is not installable. Neither 'setup.py' nor 'pyproject.toml' found.
*
So far, as comment say this git project is not instalablle because lack of setup file.

In which way should I configure it to use this API funcions in my .py file?

I tried steps that menttion in details. I am expecting someone show me proper way of configuring it.

Comment: Where your `.py`` file located ?

Comment: I mentioned in first point - just missed extension 
 C:\Users\Użytkownik\Desktop\PY_ROBOT\pyrobot.py

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to install  the required dependencies `websocket-client` and `openpyxl` :

```
pip install websocket-client==1.4.1
pip install openpyxl==3.0.10
```

See [Installation](https://github.com/caiomborges/Python-XTB-API?tab=readme-ov-file#installation) for details

As the name of the folder contain `-`you can't import it directly.

Consider renaming `Python-XTB-API` to `Python_XTB_API` and then import it :

```py
 from Python_XTB_API.API import XTB
```

You can also move `API.py` to  your project directory (`PY_ROBOT\API.py`)  and import it as:

```
from API import XTB
```

See [How to import module when module name has a '-' dash or hyphen in it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8350853/how-to-import-module-when-module-name-has-a-dash-or-hyphen-in-it) for more options.

**Note**: If you face issues using `Python  3.12.1` ,consider using `Python 3.10.4`.

Comment: So I dont need to create any env? Just copy .py files into my folder and it should work? What advantages could make generating and installing project in env environment? Saw that some git authors prefer that method.

Comment: There one `.py` file `API.py` that you need to copy to your folder . 
Create env in your folder. it good to create env for each projects.

Comment: see : https://www.quora.com/What-are-the-benefits-of-using-virtual-environments-when-developing-web-applications#:~:text=Avoid%20dependency%20conflicts%3A%20Virtual%20environments,versions%20of%20the%20same%20package.

Comment: in your case the you need to create env for your project, `Python-XTB-API` is part of it . so you do not need to create another env.