# library have "-" in name so when I call it I get SyntaxError: invalid syntax I can't change library name how can I fix it

Tags: python, import, syntax-error, importerror

[image]
I have installed pyVHR-cpu library in pycharm. Then I use this command.

```
from pyVHR-cpu.analysis.pipeline import Pipeline
```

But I have an error

```
  File "C:\Users\punnut\PycharmProjects\Deepfake_test1\DeepFAke_test1.py", line 1
    from pyVHR-cpu.analysis.pipeline import Pipeline
              ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

mean error at "-"
I try change to "_" but it said not found.

Do you other way of import library that doesn't have to call "-". I tried import in many way but it said not found. I need to use this library. What should I do? Thank you

Comment: How did you install that library? It should just be named pyVHR.

Comment: Check the docs - the library, despite this being its published name _must_ have a valid identifier package name, which is the one to be used in code.

Comment: Possible duplicate: [How to import module when module name has a '-' dash or hyphen in it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8350853/how-to-import-module-when-module-name-has-a-dash-or-hyphen-in-it)

Comment: Be careful not to confuse the name of a [distribution package](https://packaging.python.org/en/latest/glossary/#term-Distribution-Package) (the thing you install with pip) with the name(s) of the [import package(s)](https://packaging.python.org/en/latest/glossary/#term-Import-Package) it provides (the thing(s) you `import` in Python). The two need not be the same (or even similar).

Answer (score 1):

The name meant to use from code is just `pyVHR`, as in `from pyVHR.analysis.pipeline import Pipeline`

this is a must for all Python libraries, and this is the name clearly visible on the package README on pypi itself: https://pypi.org/project/pyVHR-cpu/

Comment: I have tried import pyVHR-cpu but get the same error

Comment: just do `import pyVHR`.

Comment: my computer gpu doesn't match normal pyVHR so I have to use CPU only pyVHR-cpu. I have tried normal pyVHR but can't run.

Comment: The name for install, and requirements.txt, and project dependencies is `pyVHR-cpu` - but the import name for use is just the same as the GPU enabled package: there is no change needed in the Python code.

Comment: If what is plainly wrote on the answer didn't work yet, it may be because you need to uninstall the GPU version of the package before being able to import its CPU version: `pip uninstall pyVHR && pip install -U pyVHR-cpu` on the shell might do the job.