# How to get read strings from a list(a txt file) and print them out as ints, strings, and floats?

Tags: python

I've tried literally everything to make this work. What i'm trying to do is take a file, assign each line a variable, and then set the type of the variable. It's reading it in the list as [ and ' being a line number, and I don't know what to do. I also have lists inside of the file that I need to save.
My error is:
`ValueError: invalid literal for int() for base 10: '['`

My code is:

```
def load_data():
f = open(name+".txt",'r')
enter = str(f.readlines()).rstrip('\n)
print(enter)
y = enter[0]
hp = enter[1]
coins = enter[2]
status = enter[3]
y2 = enter[4]
y3 = enter[5]
energy = enter[6]
stamina = enter[7]
item1 = enter[8]
item2 = enter[9]
item3 = enter[10]
equipped = enter[11]
firstime = enter[12]
armorpoint1 = enter[13]
armorpoint2 = enter[14]
armorpoints = enter[15]
upgradepoint1 = enter[16]
upgradepoint2 = enter[17]
firstime3 = enter[18]
firstime4 = enter[19]
part2 = enter[20]
receptionist = enter[21]
unlocklist = enter[22]
armorlist = enter[23]
heal1 = enter[24]
heal2 = enter[25]
heal3 = enter[26]
unlocked = enter[27]
unlocked2 = enter[28]
float(int(y))
int(hp)
int(coins)
str(status)
float(int(y2))
float(int(y3))
int(energy)
int(stamina)
str(item1)
str(item2)
str(item3)
str(equipped)
int(firstime)
int(armorpoint1)
int(armorpoint2)
int(armorpoints)
int(upgradepoint1)
int(upgradepoint2)
int(firstime3)
int(firstime4)
list(unlocklist)
list(armorlist)
int(heal1)
int(heal2)
int(heal3)
f.close()
SAMPLE FILE:
35.0
110
140
Sharpshooter
31.5
33
11
13
Slimer Gun
empty
empty
Protective Clothes
0
3
15
0
3
15
0
1
False
False
['Slime Slicer', 'Slimer Gun']
['Casual Clothes', 'Protective clothes']
4
3
-1
{'Protective Clothes': True}
{'Slimer Gun': True}
```

Comment: Hi please put some sample data from file.

Comment: Done! I put in some sample info.

Comment: Your code has multiple issues. 0. Open/close the file using ,`open` as a context manager. 1. Avoid reading the entire file in memory.  2. Avoid indexes. 3. Strip the `\n` after reading each line

Comment: I just did that, and now i have an error saying 'index out of range'

Comment: no need for `enter = str(f.readlines()).rstrip('\n)`  just do a for loop on readlines() and strip() on each line or you can do like enter[0].strip('\n')...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `.readlines()` function returns a list, each item containing a separate line. In order to strip the newline from each of the lines, you can use a list comprehension:

```
f = open("data.txt", "r")
lines = [line.strip() for line in f.readlines()]
```

You can then proceed to cast each item in the list separately, as you have, or try to somehow automatically infer the type in a loop. This would be easier if you formatted the example file more like a configuration file. This thread has some relevant answers:

[Best way to retrieve variable values from a text file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/924700/best-way-to-retrieve-variable-values-from-a-text-file)

Answer (score 0):

I think its better if you read the file this way, which first reads and removes whitespace and then splits into lines. Then you can set a variable to each line (also you need to set the result of changing variable types to the variable).

For lists, you may need a function to extract the list from the string. However if you aren't expecting security breaches then using `eval()` should be fine.

```
def load_data():
    f = open(name+".txt",'r')
    content = f.read().rstrip()
    lines = content.split("\n")

    y = float(int(enter[0]))
    hp = int(enter[1])
    coins = int(enter[2])
    status = enter[3]
    # (etc)

    unlocklist = eval(enter[22])
    armorlist = eval(enter[23])

    f.close()
```

Comment: for `eval()` i got an error saying 't' is not defined. Probably it reading through a string, then declaring it as a variable...?

Comment: For which line? eval(['Slime Slicer', 'Slimer Gun']) should return a list.