# Calling text from another file in python

Tags: python, file

I have some text from another python file and would like to call it into the file I'm working on, where I have labelled each section of the text `doc_1`, `doc_2`,..., `doc_13`. I have successfully imported the file, where the file is called `training`.

Here is the code:

```
from documents import training as train # imported the file

doc_labels = []
for i in range(1, 14):
    doc = f'doc_{i}'
    doc_labels.append(doc)

print(doc_labels) # This prints out a list of the document names

train_docs = []
for i in range(len(doc_labels)):
    doc = train.doc_labels[i] # trying to call the text from the documents
    train_docs.append(doc)
```

Here is the list of documents with the text, this is the training file:

```
doc_1 = """
text
"""

doc_2 = """
text
"""

.
.
.

doc_13 = """
text
"""
```

Comment: It's just loading the data and putting it into the list 'train_docs'. It's not working when I try the method above.

Comment: The text comes from the training document and the text is stored as doc_1, doc_2 and so on.

Comment: And now you want to create a list `[doc_1, doc_2, ...]`?

Comment: I think you are asking this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2612610/how-to-access-object-attribute-given-string-corresponding-to-name-of-that-attrib

Comment: Well, instead of defining multiple variables, you could define a list to begin with. Or use `getattr` to access the variables from the imported module if you can't change it to a list.

Comment: @AidanPayne can you show the code for "training"?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Can you add a seperator to the document and use `str.split(separator)`

or use [Regex101.com](https://Regex101.com) to work out what kinda match you want to do.

or check this answer [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/924700/best-way-to-retrieve-variable-values-from-a-text-file)

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).